# Django second page not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

Can any one tell me why my help page keeps returning page not found please?

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    my_dict = {'insert_me':"Hello I am from views.py !"}
    return render(request, 'first_app/index.html', context=my_dict)


def help(request):
    help_dict = {'help_insert':'HELP PAGE'}
    return render(request, 'first_app/help.html', context=help_dict)
```

First_app urls

```
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.help, name='help' ),
]
```

first_app urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

there is a template folder with first app_folder both html files are in there.
Have tried http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_app/help
and http://127.0.0.1:8000/help

What am I missing please?

Comment: First_app urls is not correct. You are adding two url in same place. Consider adding  `path(' add-something-here ', views.help, name='help' ),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to match 'help' path in url patterns.

When you write

`urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.help, name='help' ),
]`

and access http://127.0.0.1:8000/ , you will be taken to index view and since your second path is similar to first one, second path will never be matched as Django url patterns match starts from the first and ignore the similar paths present later.

to fix this, add your help path to url patterns as below,

`urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('help', views.help, name='help' ),
]`

and you can access the help page at http://127.0.0.1:8000/help

Answer (score 0):

Your `first_app/urls.py` doesn't look good.

There's no `help` path in there.